# Force variable expansion once and when used only

Tags: makefile

In this example, I have a process that takes some time. Let's says 1 second.  If I write the following `Makefile`, `FOO` will be expanded 3 times for `make all` and none for `make clean`.

If I want to save some execution time for `all` I can assign `FOO` using `:=` instead of `=`. However this will cause `FOO` to be expanded for the target clean even if it doesn't use it.

```
FOO = $(shell echo -e "+1" >> foo && echo "Hello" && sleep 1)

all:
    @echo $(FOO)
    @echo $(FOO)
    @echo $(FOO)
    @cat foo

clean:
    rm foo
```

The output:

```
$ make
Hello
Hello
Hello   
+1
+1
+1
```

I would like to force Make to expand a variable only once only if required.

Is it possible to do it so?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors

Comment: Apologies, I was going too fast earlier. I've just looked over the question and deleted answer in more detail. I'm not sure a good answer exists. I'll have to think about it some more.

Comment: The solution I've used for this sort of thing in the past, while ugly, has been to gate the assignment on the value of `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` for the targets that I know need the variable. But that doesn't scale well.

Comment: @EtanReisner yes I am currently using this workaround with a huge ifdef/endif around my Makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FOO = $(eval FOO := $(shell echo "+1" >> foo && echo "Hello" && sleep 1))$(value FOO)
```

The first time make expands `$(FOO)` it will first expand the `eval`, which resets the variable `FOO` using `:=`.  Then it resolves the value of the `FOO` variable.  In subsequent expansions, due to the `eval`, `FOO` expands directly to the value.

I should also point out that if you have at least GNU make 4.0 you can use a new feature added to the POSIX standard for make recently, [the `!=` operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html):

```
FOO != echo "+1" >> foo && echo "Hello" && sleep 1
```

which does exactly what you want here.

Comment: `!=`, while useful, doesn't have the "only if needed" property of the question though does it?

Answer (score 2):

The "best" solution I can come up with looks like this:

```
$ cat coin.mk
FOO = FOO:=$(shell echo -e "+1" >> foo && echo "Hello" && sleep 1)

defined = $(and $(filter-out undefined,$(origin $1)),$($1))

all:
        echo $(eval $(FOO))$(FOO)
        echo $(FOO)
        echo $(FOO)
        cat foo

clean:
        rm foo
$ time make -f coin.mk clean
rm foo
rm: cannot remove `foo': No such file or directory
make: *** [clean] Error 1

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time make -f coin.mk
echo Hello
Hello
echo Hello
Hello
echo Hello
Hello
cat foo
+1

real    0m1.009s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.004s
$ time make -f coin.mk clean
rm foo

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Which works but requires special-casing the first use of the variable in the make run (`$(eval $(FOO))` run a second time will cause a make error).

I tried briefly to encapsulate the eval logic *inside* the value of `FOO` but most attempts were blocked by make complaining that `*** Recursive variable 'FOO' references itself (eventually).  Stop.`